# c# odata (v4) - power bi reports: an unexpected 'StartArray' node was found

Tags: c#, odata, powerbi

I'm writing an odata web api following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)
My code is pretty much the same (some code has been removed for readability):

webapiconfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Delivery>("Versions");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public class VersionsController : ApiController
{
    DeliveryContext db = new DeliveryContext();


    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Delivery> Get()
    {
        return db.deliveries;
    }
```

DeliveryContext

```
public partial class DeliveryContext : DbContext
{
    public DeliveryContext()
        : base("name=DeliveryContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Delivery> deliveries { get; set; }

}
```

Running a GET from postman gives me:

> [{"number":-1,"customer":"","version":"","othernumber":"","identitynumber":" "},{"number":123,"customer":"i00000","version":"8.5.2","othernumber":"564","identitynumber":"123"}]

My problem is that when I'm connecting to my odataservice in Power BI it complains about:

> DataSource.Error: OData: An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.
>   Details:
>       DataSourceKind=OData
>       DataSourcePath=http://localhost:51124/Versions

Finally, postman GET to the service:
 `{
"@odata.context":"http://localhost:51124/odataservice/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"Versions","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Versions"
    }
  ]
}`

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I didn't solve my own problem but I don't have time to mess around with this anymore.
I instead followed this [guide](http://odata.github.io/RESTier/#01-01-Introduction) and got it working in 10minutes.
To be noted is that I had to use the nuget beta 1.0.0 package for it to work, otherwise I got error for the HttpConfiguration class not having a filter() method.